# How to single thread in a WebLogic 12c cluster environment

Tags: java, weblogic, cluster-computing, threadpool

I have to write an EJB hosted on a WebLogic 12c cluster that contains two servers.
The program must be single-thread, therefore both servers must not run that code at the same time.

Is there a way, other than writing custom token system, to configure my EJB to be single-threaded for the entire cluster?

Edit: here is the pseudo-code of what I had in mind when I mentioned "custom token system":

```
public void myEJBMethod() {
    String tokenUUID = getTokenFromDB("IMSToken");
    if (tokenUUID != "TokenNotAvailable") {
        doMyEJBStuff();
        releaseToken("IMSToken", tokenUUID);
    }
}

private String getTokenFromDB(String tokenName)  {
    int tokenQty=0; 
    String myThreadUUID = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    INSERT INTO TOKEN_TRACKER (TOKEN_NAME, THREAD_UUID, CREATED_DATE)  VALUE ({tokenName}, {myThreadUUID}, new Date());
    COMMIT;
    tokenQty= SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TOKEN_TRACKER WHERE TOKEN_NAME = {tokenName} AND THREAD_UUID NOT LIKE {myThreadUUID};
    if (tokenQty>0) {
        logger.trace("Token not available");
        releaseToken(tokenName, myThreadUUID);
        return "TokenNotAvailable";
    }
    else {          
        return myThreadUUID;    
    }
}

private void releaseToken(String tokenName, String tokenUIID) {
    DELETE FROM TOKEN_TRACKER WHERE THREAD_UUID = {myThreadUUID};
    COMMIT;
}
```

Comment: WebLogic Server has a Singleton Service feature to achieve such use cases
Read this post : https://developsimpler.blogspot.fr/2012/03/weblogic-clusters-and-singleton-service.html

Comment: Thanks for your input, it has great value. But I still hesitate between this option and the custom token option. I added details in the question regarding the custom token; I find it simpler (just 3 methods). However it add a point of failure, since if for any reason not catch I cannot release the token, the app will be locked and will require manual intervention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emmanuel's answer written above as a comment is probably the best one, which is to use the Singleton Service feature from WebLogic.

https://developsimpler.blogspot.ca/2012/03/weblogic-clusters-and-singleton-service.html